# Objective-C: MVC with one model and various viewcontrollers

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, model-view-controller

I have a `RootViewController` (navigation based application) that ask a model (`brain.h/m`) to perform and retrieve some information. Obviously I've instantiated a model variable first.

This is the `RootViewController.h` interface:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "Brain.h"


@interface RootViewController : UITableViewController 
{
 Brain *cerebro;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) Brain *cerebro;

@end
```

I've added a second `viewcontroller` to control a detailed view that is displayed when the user taps a row in the `tableview` of the first `viewcontroller`:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

 /*
  <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" bundle:nil];
     // ...
     // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
  [detailViewController release];
  */
```

**How can I reference and ask the model that the first `viewcontroller` had instantiated without instantiate it again in the second `viewcontroller`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a page from the [connectivity rules of capabilities programming](http://www.erights.org/elib/capability/ode/ode-capabilities.html#begets) and have the root controller introduce or endow the `Brain` to the subordinate controller.

Introduction:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController 
      = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] 
              initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" 
                       bundle:nil];
  // introduce the Brain
  detailViewController.brain = ref.to.rootController.brain;
  // ...
  // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
  [detailViewController release];
```

Endowment:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
  <#DetailViewController#> *detailViewController 
      = [[<#DetailViewController#> alloc] 
              initWithNibName:@"<#Nib name#>" 
                       bundle:nil 
                        brain:ref.to.rootController.brain];
  // ...
  // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
  [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
  [detailViewController release];
```

Comment: @outis - what's the `ref.to` syntax?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understood your question .... but i try :)

Why you not just define a property in your second controller for the model class(es) and set it e.g. during the viewDidLoad of your first controller.

Or you have a reference in all your controllers to you data model classes. A good place for data model management is the AppDelegate.

If you create a application based on the "Split View based Application" template of Xcode you get a good example.

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding this reference directly on AppDelegate to make it like a *fake* global var.

ie :

in the AppDelegate interface :

`Brain *cerebro;`

`@property (nonatomic, retain) Brain *cerebro;`

And anywhere in the code :

`[(MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] cerebro]`

should work well...

---

If you use many times, and only one `Brain` think about implementing a *singleton*

If you use many `Brain` it might be a good idea to implement a singleton `BrainManager` you could use like this :

```
Brain *cerebro = [[Brain alloc] init...]
[[BrainManager sharedManager] addBrain:cerebro withIdentifier:@"cerebro"];
```

And somewhere else :

```
[SomeThing DoTaskWithBrain:[[BrainManager sharedManager] brainWithIdentifier:@"cerebro"]];
```